# Can a module be reloaded from a different location, from within the module?

Tags: perl

I have an API A::B that's "use"d by others in their scripts like so:

```
use A::B;
my $out = A::B->new(dir => $dir);
...
```

Now, I want a *different* version of A::B to be used depending on some parameter of the attribute $dir passed to the constructor.  The user of this module has no need to know this - all he has to do is

> use A::B

in his code, and expect that the module is picked up from the right location.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: So `$dir` is the location of the different version of the module?

Comment: No, the different location will be calculated based on `$dir`.

Comment: How do you expect `use A::B;` to load the module *before* you provide the directory from which it should be loaded?

Comment: INC is already set for the tool.  It loads A::B from the standard location based on the set INC.  If the user is using `/home/myTool/2.0`, INC is set to `/home/myTool/2.0/lib` already.  However, I might want `/home/myTool/1.0/lib/A/B.pm` to be loaded instead.  (I hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messy:

```
BEGIN {
   my $version = '2.0';
   require "/home/$version/lib/A/B.pm";
}

my $obj = A::B->new();
```

---

If it's an external entity controlling the choice, then simply adjust Perl's library search path.

```
version=2.0
PERL5LIB="/home/$version/lib" script
```

```
use A::B qw( );

my $obj = A::B->new();
```

---

If it's an internal choice, use submodules instead.

```
package A::B;

sub new {
   my ($class, $version) = @_;
   $version =~ s/\./_/g;
   $class .= "::V$version";
   require $class;
   return $class->new(@_);
}

1;
```

```
use A::B qw( );

my $version = '2.0';
my $obj = A::B->new($version);
```

Comment: Thank you.  The third (edited) approach, using submodules, is what I need.  Much appreciated!

Comment: (Edited. It's now the third)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have different versions of a module with the same name.

What I would do instead is having different subclasses of `A::B`, and a *Factory* class that instantiates objects of the appropriate class, choosing and loading it based on the factory invocation parameters.

For example:

```
my $out = A::B::Factory->create( dir => $dir );
# $out is a A::B::Foo or A::B::Bar depending on $dir
```

In the factory class:

```
package A::B::Factory;
use UNIVERSAL::require;

sub create {
  my (undef, %params) = @_;

  my $dir = $params{ dir };

  # some strategy to decide which class has to be used.
  # $class will be a string like "A::B::Foo" or "A::B::Bar"
  # or in general the same of an existing class in your system.
  my $class = ...; 

  $class->use;
  return $class->new();
}
```

Comment: What I meant by version is the same module in different locations.
For instance I have `/home/1.0/lib/A/B.pm`  and `/home/2.0/lib/A/B.pm`.  The user simply says `use A::B`, and it's possible he's using v2.0 but I require that  `/home/1.0/lib/A/B.pm` be picked up and used, because (say) `$dir` passed to the constructor was created using v1.0.

Comment: What if you have two instances of `A::B` are created with different
values of `$dir`?  If one invokes a method on those instances, what
code should be executed? Even assuming we've devised a way to
dinamically reload a module based on a parameter passed to one of its
methods, Perl can only have one version of `A::B` at any given
moment. Thus, depending on what order you instantiate the objects, at
the end they would all behave the same (I mean, as 1.0 or 2.0). Hence
the idea of having *two* different names (or, in other words,
incorporating the version in the class name).

Answer (score 0):

If you allow a different package name of the other version internally (while the user still uses `A::B` and does not know about the different names of the same module), you could achieve this. For example, let's say the different version of the module is internally called `A::B::C`. Then package `A::B` could be like this:

```
package A::B;

sub new {
    my ( $class, %opts ) = @_;

    if ( $opts{dir} eq "dir1" ) {
        require A::B::C;
        return A::B::C->new();
    }
    else {
        my $self = {};
        return bless $self, $class;
    }
}

1;
```